# Execute multiple notebooks in parallel in pyspark databricks

Tags: amazon-web-services, databricks, azure-databricks, aws-databricks, databricks-community-edition

Question is simple:

**master_dim.py** calls **dim_1.py** and **dim_2.py** to execute in parallel. Is this possible in databricks pyspark?

Below image is explaning what am trying to do, it errors for some reason, am i missing something here?

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just for others in case they are after how it worked:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
pool = ThreadPool(5)
notebooks = ['dim_1', 'dim_2']
pool.map(lambda path: dbutils.notebook.run("/Test/Threading/"+path, timeout_seconds= 60, arguments={"input-data": path}),notebooks)
```

Comment: you can just use `path` - in this case it's easier to move project into new folder, etc. if the `path` isn't absolute, then it's treated as relative to the current notebook

Comment: The limitation with this approach is you can't share dependencies with the parallel jobs. I hope databricks can improve this so we can pass not only strings to the called notebook

Comment: I will create level 2 list and run after the level 1 list has completed. Gives control.

Answer (score 5):

your problem is that you're passing only `Test/` as first argument to the `dbutils.notebook.run` (the name of notebook to execute), but you don't have notebook with such name.

You need either modify list of paths from `['Threading/dim_1', 'Threading/dim_2']` to `['dim_1', 'dim_2']` and replace `dbutils.notebook.run('Test/', ...)` with `dbutils.notebook.run(path, ...)`

Or change `dbutils.notebook.run('Test/', ...)` to `dbutils.notebook.run('/Test/' + path, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Databricks now has *workflows/multitask jobs*. Your master_dim can call other jobs to execute in parallel after finishing/passing taskvalue parameters to dim_1, dim_2 etc.